# Как сделать тень от объекта используя фильтр feOffset?

Tags: svg, svg-animation

Как сделать тень от объекта используя фильтр feOffset?

```html
<svg width='400' height='400' viewBox='0 0 400 400' style='border: 1px solid black;';>
  <filter id='a'>
    <feOffset dy='12' dx='12'></feOffset>
  </filter>
  <rect x="50" y="50" width="100" height="50" fill="red" id='#a'/>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Тень с двух сторон

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="-50 -50 200 200">
  
  <defs>
    <filter id="dropshadow" height="130%">
      <feGaussianBlur in="SourceAlpha" stdDeviation="3"/> 
      <feOffset dx="2" dy="2" result="offsetblur"/> 
      <feMerge> 
        <feMergeNode/>
        <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic"/> 
      </feMerge>
    </filter>
  </defs>
  <polygon points="58.263,0.056 100,41.85 58.263,83.641 30.662,83.641 62.438,51.866 0,51.866 0,31.611 62.213,31.611 30.605,0 58.263,0.056" fill="#EEEEEE" filter="url(#dropshadow)"/>
</svg>
```

### Пример анимации тени

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="-50 -15 250 250">
  
  <defs>
    <filter id="dropshadow" height="150%" width="150%">
      <feGaussianBlur in="SourceAlpha" stdDeviation="2"/> 
      <feOffset dx="0" dy="2" result="offsetblur">
        <animate attributeName="dx" begin="0s" dur="4s" values="-2;0;0;2;0;-2;-2" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
    <animate attributeName="dy" begin="0s" dur="4s" values="-2;0;0;2;0;-2;-2" repeatCount="indefinite" />
    </feoffset>   
      <feMerge> 
        <feMergeNode/>
        <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic"/> 
      </feMerge>
    </filter>
  </defs>
  <polygon points="58.263,0.056 100,41.85 58.263,83.641 30.662,83.641 62.438,51.866 0,51.866 0,31.611 62.213,31.611 30.605,0 58.263,0.056"  fill="#E74245" filter="url(#dropshadow)"/>
</svg>
```

**Update**

*Пример анимации тени с перемещением источника света*

```html
<svg width="100vw" height="100vh"
version="1.1"
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"> 

  <radialGradient id="gradientRed" 
    cx="50%" cy="50%" r="100%" fx="20%" fy="10%">
    <animate attributeName="fy" dur="6s" values="10%;90%;10%" 
     repeatCount="indefinite" />
   <stop stop-color="white" offset="0"/>
   <stop stop-color="red" offset="25%"/>
   <stop stop-color="rgb(192,0,0)" offset="50%"/>
   <stop stop-color="rgb(127,0,0)" offset="70%"/>
   <stop stop-color="rgb(64,0,0)" offset="85%"/>
   <stop stop-color="rgb(0,0,0)" offset="100%"/>
  </radialGradient>

  <filter id="shadow" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse" 
      width="200%" height="200%"> 
     <feGaussianBlur in="SourceAlpha" 
       result="inShadow" stdDeviation="10" />
     <feOffset in="inShadow" result="myShadow" dx="35" dy="45">
      <animate attributeName="dy" dur="6s" values="35;-35;35"
           repeatCount="indefinite" />
     </feOffset>
     <feBlend in="SourceGraphic" in2="myShadow" mode="normal"/>
  </filter>

  <circle id="myCircle" cx="50%" cy="50%" r="20%" 
     fill="url(#gradientRed)" 
     filter="url(#shadow)"  >
  </circle>


</svg>
```

*Полезные ссылки на русском объясняющие работу примененных фильтров:*

[feGaussianBlur](https://www.intuit.ru/studies/courses/1063/210/lecture/5436?page=2)

[feMerge](https://www.intuit.ru/studies/courses/1063/210/lecture/5436?page=4)

[feComposite](https://www.intuit.ru/studies/courses/1063/210/lecture/5436?page=5)

Answer (score 4):

dy - двигает фильтр по вертикали

dx - двигает по горизонтали

Обязательно помещаем filter между тегами `defs`

Тень делается вот таким образом

```html
<svg width='400' height='400' viewBox='0 0 400 400' style='border: 1px solid black;' ;>
  <defs>
    <filter id='a' filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse" >
                <feGaussianBlur in="SourceAlpha" stdDeviation="4.2"/>
                <feOffset dx="12" dy="12" result="offsetblur"/>
                <feFlood flood-color="rgba(255,0,0,0.5)"/>
                <feComposite in2="offsetblur" operator="in"/>
                <feMerge>
                        <feMergeNode/>
                        <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic"/>
                </feMerge>
    </filter>
  </defs>
  
  <rect x="50" y="50" width="100" height="50" fill="red" filter="url(#a)"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: маленькое замечание: совсем необязательно помещать `filter` в секцию `<defs>` так как в отличии от линий, фильтр пока не применен никак не проявляет себя и никому не мешает (+)

Comment: я не спорю - но привычка у меня такая

Comment: правильная привычка!